# go to a specific minute in an audio

Tags: jquery, audio

How to go to a specific minute in an audio file?
The play button works well. Is there something similar to go for instance to the second 20? 
Something that could work in any browser, not only html5 (like the button play here)
Here is a place to check: http://jsfiddle.net/K7W78/

jQUERY:

```
$(function(){        
    $("#play").click(function() {
      $("#audio").trigger('play');
    });

    $("#minute").click(function() {
      $("#audio").something? 
    }); 
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="play">Play</div>
<div id="minute">Minute</div>
<audio id="audio" src="http://a3.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/075/Music/35/e5/c6/mzm.pffzpdco.aac.p.m4a">
</audio>
```

Comment: In case it wasn't clear, you'd do that like so -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/K7W78/1/)

Comment: @adeneo: yes, this is it. But I do not understand what you have added to the html? is it really necessary? I think it works without that

Comment: It's not neccessary, it just shows the progress to show that it's skipping when you click the button.